# Deleting A Specified Substring in Java

Tags: java, string, substring

This is actually an exercise from **CodingBat**. The definition of the problem is as follows:

> Given a string, if the string "del" appears starting at index 1, return a string where that "del" has been deleted. Otherwise, return the string unchanged.
>
> - delDel("adelbc") → "abc"
> - delDel("adelHello") → "aHello"
> - delDel("adedbc") → "adedbc"

My work is as follows:

```
public String delDel(String str) {
  String del = "del";

  if (str.indexOf(del, 1) == 1){
    str.replaceFirst("del", null);
  }

  return str;
}
```

It works fine for most of the cases, but I get *NullPointerException* in "**adelbc**", "**adelHello**" and "**adel**" cases. I can't quite understand why.

Comment: I assume CodingBat only requires you to provide a function with the given signature and then runs the tests on it?

Comment: What about if you use `""` - an empty string - instead of null? Maybe the JRE runs something on the replacing string. It's quite weird to use null here.

Comment: Just tested it locally. Using `null` as the string to replace with throws a `NullPointerException`. `""` is definitely what you want to do.

Comment: @mszymborski There were exercises that I have solved in a different way compared to pre-defined code

Comment: Doesn't `replaceFirst` return a new string? Your answer would have been incorrect anyways, since you return the original string

Comment: @cricket_007 I return the original string if it does not contain the specified sub-string. If it does, my if statement works and modifies the given string, then returns the modified string

Comment: @Non-Existent - it can't possibly work, strings in Java are immutable - that is unmodifiable. Throw a nice `return` in the fifth line.

Comment: No it doesn't. `str` is not modified "in-place". You are always returning the original string

Comment: Okay I got the idea, thanks for the help everybody!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you look closely in the OpenJDK sources, you'll note that replaceFirst delegates work to the regexp functions, including this one for replacing step:

```
public String replaceFirst(String replacement) {
    if (replacement == null)
        throw new NullPointerException("replacement");
    reset();
    if (!find())
        return text.toString();
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    appendReplacement(sb, replacement);
    appendTail(sb);
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Note that replacement can not be null. I assume the behaviour is going to be similar in other implementations of the JRE. Please use `""` - empty string - instead of null as the replacement.

Also as mentioned in the comments by `cricket_007` you want to save the result of `replaceFirst` for returning, since the original string will not be affected (all Strings in Java are immutable). The final piece of code:

```
public String delDel(String str) {
  String del = "del";

  if (str.indexOf(del, 1) == 1){
    return str.replaceFirst("del", "");
  }

  return str;
}
```

Comment: @cricket_007: sorry for that. Fortunately you have licence to edit ;)